# jQuery .slide and .slideUp. Not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide

I have make this script:

```
$("#comments .comment .links").hide();
$("#comments .comment").hover(
    function() { $(".links", this).stop(true).slideDown(300); },
    function() { $(".links", this).stop(true).slideUp(300); }
);
```

Now i have a problem. When i hover over the comment divs. And I hover a few times. That .links div is not showing anymore. The div is not fully open.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Try adding another true in the stops `.stop(true,true)`

Comment: Can you post the html related to the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#comments .comment .links").hide();
$("#comments .comment").hover(
    function() { $(".links", this).not(":animated").slideDown(300); },
    function() { $(".links", this).not(":animated").slideUp(300); }
);
```

OR

```
$("#comments .comment .links").hide();
$("#comments .comment").hover(
    function() { 
                  $(".links", this).stop(true, true).slideToggle();
               }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little modification and you have this.

```
$("#comments .comment .links").hide();
$("#comments .comment").hover(
    function() { $(".links", this).stop(true, true).slideDown(300); },
    function() { $(".links", this).stop(true, true).slideUp(300); }
);​
```